# Tengo errores en mi codigo pero no se solucionarlos

Tags: c++, c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const static size_t NUM_COLS = 80;
const static size_t NUM_ROWS = 25;

struct Char {
    uint8_t character;
    uint8_t color;
};

struct Char* buffer = (struct Char*) 0xb8000;
size_t col = 0;
size_t row = 0;
uint8_t color = PRINT_COLOR_WHITE | PRINT_COLOR_BLACK << 4;

void clear_row(size_t row) {
    struct Char empty = (struct Char) {
        character: ' ',
        color: color,
    };

    for (size_t col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++) {
        buffer[col + NUM_COLS * row] = empty;
    }
}
```

Me da errores en la función clear_row, me dice que character no está definido, que en los : que estan despues de character deberia de haber un }, que en los : despues de color deberia de haber ; y en el for me dice "se esperaba una declaracion". Si alguien me puede echar una mano lo agradeceria mucho.

Gracias.

Comment: Al pegar el codigo en mi editor no me marca errores, lo que me marca es una advertencia por usar los field designartors de gnu, pero errores no. Puedes enviarnos en especifico el error que te sale?

Comment: @Pablochaches he puesto una captura de los errores que me da.

Comment: Estas utilizando un compilador de C o de C++?

Answer (score 0):

Los dos puntos (:) no es un operador de asignación, como al parecer haces tu en tu código, creo que lo que quieres hacer es lo siguiente:

```
    character = ' ';
    color = color;
```

Como puedes ver, terminado en punto y coma, no en una simple coma.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, voy a provar si funciona.